# isotope masonry responsive layout not arranging

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see, the images are behaving rather weird, they do not arrange themselves until the browser width gets rather small. What am i doing wrong ? I notice as the window gets smaller, the items have overlapping dimnesions.

HTML

```
    <div class="masonry container">
        <div class="col-sizer"></div>
        <div class="item width2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-1.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-2.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item height2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-3.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-4.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-5.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-6.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-7.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-8.png" alt="a"> </div>
        <div class="item width2"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/sc/masonry-9.png" alt="a"> </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.masonry .item {
    float: left;
    max-width: 25%;
    max-height: 244px;
}

.masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-sizer {
    max-width: 25%;
}

.masonry .item.width2 {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.masonry .item.height2 {
    max-height: 488px;
}
```

JQUERY (on document ready)

```
$(".masonry").isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry:{
        columnWidth: $(".masonry").find('.col-sizer')[0]            
    }
})

$(".masonry").isotope('layout')
```

Comment: Is there any production link?

Comment: i added the link to the live website as well

Comment: What if you apply an HTML 5 CSS reset?

Comment: doesn't bootstrap have one? because if it does, then i already have one

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because **you load Masonry before images load** : Masonry calculate positions of your items without the size of your images. That's why it breaks.

You need to call Masonry after that, like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){ // wait for all to be loaded and do the job
 $(".masonry").isotope({
  itemSelector : '.item',
  layoutMode : 'masonry'

});
```

You can also check for ImagesLoaded : http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/ , a plugin by the creator of Masonry, it does the same thing.

Comment: i tried your solution and it doesn't make a difference. take a look at the live website to see how it behaves

Comment: You set an object ($(".masonry").find('.col-sizer')[0] to the columnWidth... Check my edit.

Comment: that makes it behave better but it still has issues

Comment: First, remove the last line, it has nothing to do here. Then, I edited my answer with the basic setup of Isotope.

Comment: this indeed gets me closer. however it doesn't seem to work as expected because it leaves the empty spaces there without arranging them like masonry should

Comment: i also added an edit to the css, bringing it even closer to my desired result

Comment: it's because you selected 'fitRows' layout, try putting 'masonry' (edited my code).

Comment: i also tried that, but as you can now see it calculates it rather oddly, not giving the expected result (updated the live site)